# Synchrony - the second function starts before, the first function ends

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I'm building a website in Javascript, and I have this problem:

I want to do something like that.

First function calls server X.

The second function also calls server X, but only after the first is completely finished.

```js
func2afterFunc1 = async () => {
    await func1Open();
    await func2Use();
  }
```

```js
export const func1Open = () => (dispatch) => {
    axios
        .post('/callToFunc1', "")
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
};

//basically call to this function to signup

exports.callToFunc1 = (req, res) => {
    serverX
        .open()
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data)
            return res.status(201).json("wasOpen");
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
            return res.status(500).json("error");
        });
};
```

```js
export const func2Use = (user) => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        serverX
            .useAfterOpened()
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: func1Open returns void, and not a promise so awaiting it does nothing

Comment: Thanks for the help, when can I do if I have no promise but I need synchronization?

Comment: You can't. If you have asynchronous code, the only way to have something happen after the asynchronous code completes is with a callback, which is exactly what a Promise models. But you should have a promise, because axios.post returns a promise. You're even using the .then(), which returns another promise. Just add a return before `axios.post` in `func1Open`.

Comment: Also keep in mind that `.then` on a Promise behaves similar to `.map` on an array, where the value transforms based on the return of the callback function. So when you `.then((res) => console.log(res))`, you're actually transforming the promise to return undefined. You're not using the value in your await though, so this isn't a big deal.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it probably works now, I fixed as you told me.